# Django static files are not accessible

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a django project and tried to use an HTML template; however, I get an error while accessing files in static folder.

Here is my configuration:

```
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

I have added static variable at the top of the HTML file as:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Travello</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Travello template project">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link href="{% static 'plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'  %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/main_styles.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/responsive.css' %}">
.....(cont'd)
```

The following is my folder configuration:

```
-my_project
--assets
--my_project
--static
--templates
--travello
```

My problem is that:

1. I cannot access images in static folder from browser, that is, when I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/about_1.jpg, I get an error like **Page not found (404)**
2. When I type http://127.0.0.1:8000 in order to see the **index.html** main page, I get the page with lots of errors saying **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Could you please help me in order to solve this issue. I will be glad to here your answers, thanks.

Comment: I have tried a lot from the internet to solve it; however, none of them worked for me. I suspect that there is a problem with permission. Could it be the problem? Maybe, somehow I need to change the permission for the client to reach the static files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run `python manage.py collectstatic`, to copy all project's static files to your STATIC_ROOT dir - this should solve your second issue.

The first one is caused by incorrect URL address. You have set STATIC_ROOT to 'assets' dir, but you try to get access to the image entering `/static/images/about_1.jpg`. Just try `/static/assets/about_1.jpg` or `/static/assets/images/about_1.jpg` if `images` dir actually exists

Comment: when I try `python manage.py collectstatic` not all files are transferred to assets folder. I expeced that all the files to be transferred but that is not the case.

Comment: Since assets folder is not containing my files I have typed the url as above.

Comment: Could you please print the content of your assets directory?. IMHO if everything is configured properly, there're only two posible reasons of this situation:
1. incorrect URL
2. file does not exist in the given location